# Is there Any Alternative For X509Certificate2UI in ASP.net Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

```
X509Certificate2Collection sel = X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection(
    Filteredcollection, 
    "Certificates", 
    "Select a Certificate to sign", 
    X509SelectionFlag.SingleSelection
);
```

`X509Certificate2UI` is giving an error at this point in asp.net core

Answer (score 1):

No. X509CertificateUI is meant to pop up a selection UI on the Windows Desktop. For the web the selection process is enforced by the browser, not by any code on the server.

You must configure your web site to only accept certificates, how you do that depends on the hosting software.

For Kestrel it's in code;

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
       .UseStartup<Startup>()
       .UseKestrel(options =>
       {
           options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 5001, listenOptions =>
           {
               listenOptions.UseHttps(new HttpsConnectionAdapterOptions
               {
                   ServerCertificate = /* Your HTTPS Certificate */,
                   ClientCertificateMode = ClientCertificateMode.RequireCertificate,
                   ClientCertificateValidation = /* Validator */
               });
           });
       })
       .Build();
```

For IIS it's through the UI,

1. Select your Site in the Connections tab.
2. Double click the SSL Settings in the Features View window.
3. Check the Require SSL Check Box and select the Require radio button under Client Certificates.

[image]

Comment: So how can i pop up a selection UI in mac and linux using c#  @blowdart

Comment: You config the hosting web site to require certificates and the browser takes care of it

Comment: You may use Browser Extension like Signer Digital or other to select certificates on browser, in web application.